# Помогите в проекте правильно отправить форму и записать данные в БД

Tags: c#, html, mysql, база-данных, mvc

Нужен правильный запрос. Есть проект в котором автопарк по типам транспорта. У каждого типа свои атрибуты и у атрибутов своя таблица. При добавлении новой техники нужно записать сколько записей, сколько атрибутов у данного вида техники.
То есть при данном типе в таблицу
ID, NAME, TYPE, ID_ATRIBUTA, VALUE записать все атрибуты транспорта их 3, то есть записей должно стать 4, например:

1, мерседес, транспорт, 4(вес), 2000
2, мерседес, транспорт, 5(год), 1995
3, мерседес, транспорт,7 (цвет), черный.

Далее меняем тип на ПК, тогда меняются атрибуты и в ID, NAME, TYPE, ID_ATRIBUTA, VALUE пойдут:

4, Леново, транспорт, 1(разрядность), х64
5, Леново, транспорт, 9(цвет), серый
6, Леново, транспорт, 12(год), 2010
7, Леново, транспорт, 16(размер), 15дюймов

```
<form>
<input name=“name”>
<input readonly name=“type” value=“транспорт”> </input>
 @foreach (var att in ViewBag.listAtt)
 {
         <input required name="@att.Id" />
 }
<button>отправить</button>
</form>
```